# Google Apps won't flash on HTC Desire (Cyanogenmod)

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire, google-apps

One of my co-workers has a HTC Desire CDMA phone and is having a problem with flashing CM7 with Google Apps.  It flashes CM7 just fine, and it even says that it installs the Google Apps zip (the GB version) just fine, but in reality, it isn't flashing any of the Google applications. I can try manually flashing the gapps zip file and it will still say it installs successfully, but there are still no Google Apps on the phone.

What else can I try to get Google Apps installed on his phone?

Comment: Did you reboot the phone before any of these flashes?

Comment: @JonnyP the first flash was via Rom Manager. When I tried to manually flash it, I booted it into recovery and flashed from the gapps zip file on the sdcard

Comment: @JonnyP so I guess my question back is: does booting from phone into recovery not count as a reboot? Do I need to turn it completely off and then boot into recovery?

Comment: What version of CWM Recovery is the phone running?

Comment: In my (admittedly very limited) experience doing a normal reboot and then rebooting into recovery seem to have different effects on the phone.  When I originally flashed CM6.2.1 on my Droid I installed it via ROM Manager and then had similar issues with GApps, so I rebooted the phone, let it come back up naturally, and then re-flashed the GApps and I ended up getting them on successfully that time.  Obviously though with the phones being different and no guarantee that my issue was the same as yours your results may vary.

Comment: @eldarerathis Clockworkmod 2.5.0.9 (it says that is the latest version)

Comment: @Bryan: The 3.x series is the latest on other devices, did the Desire not get the update?

Comment: @eldareathis I'm not sure, I'll have to research. The only other CWM recoveries RomManager would let me flash were 2.5.1.x versions.

Comment: @Bryan: I found a thread on the CM forums where people were having the same problem. I also tracked down the 3.0.0.5 (testing?) release of CWM for the Desire. Added an answer below, see if any of that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people are reporting success by simply wiping data and cache first, then flashing the ROM, wiping cache again, then flashing the Gapps package. Thread on the CM forums [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/15493-cant-get-google-apps-installed/) (from CM 6.1.1, don't know if it's a related or similar problem, though).

The flash might not work on a 2.x release of CWM. You can get 3.0.0.5 [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=839640), but I don't know how stable it is right now. The filesystem changed to `ext4` in Gingerbread and I know the 2.x releases aren't really supported on other devices. They also changed from one update scripting language to another, which I think is related. It creates generally weird behavior from what I've read...

Edit: Also looks like you can get CWM 3.0.2.8 from the [CyanogenMod Forums](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/19695-latest-version-of-clockwork-mod/) now.

Some relevant discussion can be found on XDA [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=920511) (from the Desire HD section).

**Edit:** Since Bryan noted that this solved it for him in the comments: It's also possible to simply push the apps manually onto the system partition. The safest way is probably to boot into recovery, then just mount `/system` as rw and `adb push` the .apk files to `/system/app`. You probably *could* do it from a regular boot (not in recovery) but it might cause some weird behavior (and I have not personally tried this).

Comment: I'll grab his phone again and try the wipe --> flash CM7 --> wipe cache --> flash Gapps. If that doesn't work I'll see if I can get 3.x recovery on the phone

Comment: @eldarerathis Had no luck doing either method. We flashed CWM 3.0.2.8, then wiped data/cache, flashed CM7, wiped cache again, and flashed Gapps.  Still no Google apps showing up

Comment: @Bryan: That's truly bizarre...out of curiosity, can you manually mount the `/system` partition in rw mode from recovery? That's usually the sticking point for this kind of thing, but the issue usually seems to be resolved by going from CWM 2.x -> 3.x. Incidentally, I suppose you could try manually pushing the .apks to `/system/app` in recovery mode if the mount works.

Comment: @eldareathis I can manually mount /system. I've flashed CW 3.x and still no luck.  System/apps/ is not showing the apps after flashing the gapps zip (although it says it was successful).  I think I'll try manually pushing the apks.

Comment: adb pushing the contents of the gapps.zip to the system partition worked :)

Comment: @Bryan: Well that was a random shot in the dark, but glad it helped!

Comment: @eldareathis Yeah, this was very weird. It basically wasn't flashing the gapps.zip although it reported no problems. And fixing permissions in recovery didn't work either. If all else fails, push it yourself :)